# How to transform each row to have a unique column

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL server 2012 and I want to get a csv about check no and item name to do market bucket analysis;

Current data output;

```
Check No    Item Name
1010000001  3/4 Time Session Ale
1010000001  Aquilani Gls
1010000001  Australian Psycho 50L
1010000001  Bloody Mary
1010000001  Brookvale Ginger Beer
1010000001  Buffalo Trace
1010000001  CafÃ© Latte
1010000001  Cake Sparkling Gls
1010000001  Cap
1010000001  Capi Blood Orange
1010000001  Capi Dry Ginger
1010000002  Capi Pink Grapefruit
1010000002  Capi Soda
1010000002  Capi Sparkling Mineral
1010000002  Capi Yuzu
1010000002  Cappucino
1010000002  Carlton Draught
1010000002  Catalina Sounds Gls
1010000002  Chicken Taco
1010000002  Chivas Regal 12 Yr
1010000002  Coke
1010000002  Corona
```

Expected output;

```
1010000001 | 3/4 Time Session Ale | Aquilani Gls | Australian Psycho 50L etc
```

I have used the following code;

```
SELECT [CheckNo], 
       Items = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [itemModName1]
                      FROM tbl_item AS T1
                      WHERE T1.[CheckNo] = T2.[CheckNo]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM tbl_item AS T2
GROUP BY [CheckNo];
```

Results;

it gives me all the items in one column which is not helpful.

Comment: STUFF will return you all row's value in one column delimited by the provided delimiter and you are getting results accordingly. Output also matching with your provided expectation. Please clarify more what your are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not clear what you mean by "it gives me all the items in one column which is not helpful."

From a quick inspection of your code, I see two issues.

1. `GROUP BY` should not be there. The aggregation of the text is performed by `XML PATH`. By using an additional `GROUP BY`, I expect that your query should not work as the second column is not an aggregation function.
2. You use ', ' as a delimiter, which has length 2, but you only remove 1 char at the beginning with `STUFF`, which will lead to a space in the beginning. Not a terrible thing, but still.

So I recommend trying:

```
SELECT [CheckNo], 
       Items = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [itemModName1]
                      FROM tbl_item AS T1
                      WHERE T1.[CheckNo] = T2.[CheckNo]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM tbl_item AS T2;
```

Comment: I removed my answer (which looks a lot like yours) 15 minutes ago. The OP is indeed not very clear about his desired result. After posting my answer and looking at mkRabbani's comment, I assumed my answer was wrong and the result should dynamically include columns for each separate itemModName1 value per CheckNo. Something like a pivot table, but then even more dynamical. Since I assumed this is neither a trivial task nor a fitting task for SQL, I totally abandoned my answer and ignored this question altogether.

Comment: Oh, so you mean OP uses | to signify different columns. Surely their use of xml path is misleading, if this is the case.